# order by field = value asc equivalent with spring Sort.by

Tags: java, sql, spring, sorting, sql-order-by

i have a query in db like `order by <field> = <value>`, it gets first the records which have the value at the field then the rest. I need to write equivalent sort with Sort.By of spring. Is there a anyway to put value in sort like `Sort.by("field" == "value")`

Thanks in advance